# How can I sort a list in java by another list of ids

Tags: java, sorting

I have a list of objects in java that looks something like this:

```
List<Video> videos = new ArrayList<Video>();
```

and my video object looks like this:

```
public class Video {
    private String nameId;
    private Integer id;
    ...
}
```

I have another list that just has my nameId strings:

```
List<String> nameIdList = ArrayList<String>();
```

How can I write a compareto method that doesn't sort my list of videos by comparing each video and instead uses another list? My approach so far has been to use a simple bubble sort but that will be very inefficient as my list gets bigger

Example:

I could have video objects with nameIds : "apple", "bannana", "orange"

and my list of strings to sort them by could be: "bannana", "apple", "orange"

so my videos I would want to return to my client should be in the order of: "bannana", "apple", "orange"

Comment: I'm also using java 7 btw so I can't use streams

Comment: Could you post a sample input / output? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Are you defining an order based on "another list", e.g. {"A New Hope", "The Empire Strikes Back", "Return of the Jedi"}?

Comment: I've added an example to my question. @rgettman yes I'm defining the order based on another list. sorry for the confusion

Comment: What happens when you encounter "pear" which isn't in the sort order definition?

Comment: if "pear" was in my list of strings, I would want to just skip that since there doesn't exist a video with a nameId of "pear"

Answer (score 30):

Java 8:

```
videos.sort(Comparator.comparing(v->nameIdList.indexOf(v.getNameId())));
```

this is smaller than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36210664/3044680)

Answer (score 5):

A simple and clean solution, which surprisingly has not been mentioned:

```
videos.sort(Ordering.explicit(nameIdList).onResultOf(Video::getNameId));
```

[Ordering.explicit](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#explicit-java.util.List-) is part of Guava.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom Comparator

```
List<String> nameIdList = new ArrayList<>();
Comparator<Video> compare = new Comparator<Video>() {
     public int compare(Video v1, Video v2) {
         return nameIdList.indexOf(v1.getNameId()) - nameIdList.indexOf(v2.getNameId());
     }
};
```

To make this more efficient you could have a `Map<String, Integer>` so you can look up the desired order more efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the lists involved are **very** long, I would use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36210664/3973077) solution, but here is an alternative solution that has time complexity `O(n)`. Any solution using a `Comparator` together with `Collections.sort` or `Arrays.sort` has time complexity no better than `O(n log n)`.

The method sorts the list `videos` based on the other list, and clears away any `Video` whose `nameId` is not in the list.

```
public static void sort(List<Video> videos, List<String> list) {
    Map<String, List<Video>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String string : list)
        map.put(string, new ArrayList<>());
    for (Video video : videos) {
        List<Video> value = map.get(video.getNameId());
        if (value != null)
            value.add(video);
    }
    videos.clear();
    for (String string : list)
        for (Video video : map.get(string))
            videos.add(video);
}
```

Comment: Above code works only if `List<String> list` is sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Java 8. Convert to map and pick by hash:

```
Map<String, Video> videoMap = videos.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Video::getNameId, v -> v));

return videos.stream()
         .map(v -> videoMap.get(v))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 8 stream

```
List<Video> orderedList=
              nameIdList.stream()
                  .map(
                      s ->
                          videos.stream()
                              .filter(v -> v.get_id().equals(s))
                              .findFirst()
                              .orElse(null))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```